# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{nm}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{nm}$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $a_{nm}\in\mathbb{R}$ so that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty |a_{nm}|<\infty$. Show $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{nm}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{nm}$.

Comment: Prove it first for $a_{m,n}\ge0$ and then deduce the general case.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2063217/148510) may help.  Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2329383/148510).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we let $\mu$ be the counting measure, then it is just a special case of Fubini's Theorem to $d\mu(m)\times d\mu(n)$.